# Listas enlazadas, error imprimir datos

Tags: c++, dev-c++, nodos, memoria, queue

tengo una cola con una estructura, a la cual, mediante una función **void**, le ingreso el campo grupo y esa misma función llama a otras para agregar datos a los **vectores** de **alumnos** y **materias**; el problema es que al intentar imprimir los datos que hay en vector alumnos y el vector materias se deja de ejecutar el programa

```cpp
typedef struct Grupo {
    char grupo[10];
    vector<string> alumnos{};
    vector<string> materias{};
    Grupo *next;
};
Grupo *grupos;          //auxiliar
Grupo *start_gpr;       //inicio de nodo
Grupo *end_gpr;         //fin de nodo
//matriz dinamica => notas
float **grades = NULL;

int contGrupo = 1;
bool new_gpr_bool = true;
static int a_, m_, tGrupos, tAlumnos, tMaterias, new_gpr_int;
static float nota;
static string almn, gpr;

//cola
void startQueue(bool &);

//DM => matriz
void memoriaN(int &, int &);

//escritura de datos
void writeGrupo(int &);
void addA(string &);
void addM(string &);
void writeNotas(float, int &, int &);

//inicializa la cola
void startQueue(bool &new_gpr_) {
    start_gpr = NULL;
    end_gpr = NULL;

    while(new_gpr_) {
        grupos = new Grupo;

        writeGrupo(contGrupo);

        if(start_gpr == NULL) {
            start_gpr = grupos;
            end_gpr = grupos;
            grupos->next = NULL;
        }
        else {
            end_gpr->next = grupos;
            grupos->next = NULL;
            end_gpr = grupos;
        }
        cout<<"agregar otro grupo: [1] Si [2] No\n";
        cin>>new_gpr_int;

        (new_gpr_int == 1) ? new_gpr_ = true : new_gpr_ = false;
    }
}

//escritura de datos de struct Grupo
void writeGrupo(int &cont) {
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"--- GRUPO ["<<cont<<"] ---"<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre (grupo): ";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin.getline(grupos->grupo, 10, '\n');
    strupr(grupos->grupo);

    cout<<"\n--- "<<grupos->grupo<<": ALUMNOS ---"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nnumero de alumnos: ";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin>>a_;

    //llamada en bucle addA()
    for(int i = 0; i < a_; i++) {
        addA(almn);
    }

    cout<<"\n--- "<<grupos->grupo<<": MATERIAS ---"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nnumero de materias: ";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin>>m_;

    //llamada en bucle addM()
    for(int i = 0; i < m_; i++) {
        addM(gpr);
    }

    tAlumnos = a_;                  //largo de vector alumnos
    tMaterias = m_;                 //largo de vector materias
    //tAlumnos = grupos->alumnos.size();
    //tMaterias = grupos->materias.size();

    //reservacion de memoria
    memoriaN(tAlumnos, tMaterias);

    cout<<"\nta:"<<tAlumnos<<"\ntm:"<<tMaterias<<endl;

    cout<<"--- "<<grupos->grupo<<": CALIFICACIONES ---"<<endl;
    cin.sync();

    writeNotas(nota, tAlumnos, tMaterias);

    cont++;
}

void addA(string &str) {
    cout<<"GRUPO ["<<contGrupo<<"] "<<"Nombre (alumno): ";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin>>str;

    cin.sync();

    grupos->materias.push_back(str);
}

void addM(string &str) {
    cout<<"GRUPO ["<<contGrupo<<"] "<<"Nombre (materia): ";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin>>str;

    cin.sync();

    grupos->materias.push_back(str);
}

void memoriaN(int &rows, int &columns) {
    grades = new float *[rows];

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        grades[r] = new float[columns];
    }
}

void writeNotas(float cal, int &tA, int &tM) {
    for(int a = 0; a < tA; a++) {
        for(int m = 0; m < tM; m++) {
            cout<<grupos->alumnos[a]<<":" ;
            cout<<grupos->materias[m]<<endl;
            cout<<"Calificacion: ";
            fflush(stdin);
            cin>>cal;

            grades[a][m] = cal;
        }
    }
}
```

en la funcion **writeGrupo(int&)** sustituí la obtención del tamaño del vector debido a que no me arrojaba ningun tamaño real por lo que no se asignaba memoria a la matriz, tal vez el problema este en las funciones de **addA(string&)** **addM(string&)** y no se están llenando de manera correcta

```
tAlumnos = grupos->alumnos.size(); //arroja 0
tMaterias = grupos->materias.size(); //arroja la suma de las variables a_ y m_ solicitadas en writeGrupo(int&)
```

en la funcion **writeNotas(float, int&, int&)** el problema se encuentra en la impresión del nombre de la materia y del nombre del alumno, ya que si quito estas lineas, el programa continua su ejecución

```
cout<<grupos->alumnos[a]<<": ";
cout<<grupos->materias[m]<<endl;
```

Comment: Por favor, coloca un código mínimo, completo y verificable (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ya que es difícil entender cuál es la causa del error a partir de los trozos de código que has colocado

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla he agregado más código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error se encontraba en el llenado de los **vectores** **alumnos** y **materias** de la **estructura**, en ambas funciones tenia la sentencia

```
grupos->materias.push_back(str);
```

```
void addA(string &str) {
    cout<<"GRUPO ["<<contGrupo<<"] "<<"Nombre (alumno): ";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin>>str;

    cin.sync();

    grupos->materias.push_back(str); //cambiar a vector alumnos
}

void addM(string &str) {
    cout<<"GRUPO ["<<contGrupo<<"] "<<"Nombre (materia): ";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin>>str;

    cin.sync();

    grupos->materias.push_back(str);
}
```